# Resolving "ERROR: could not open extension control file" from "create extension postgis;' for PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgis, installation, postgresql-10

I am receiving this error when I `create extension postgis;`:

> SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open extension control file
>   "C:/POSTGR~1/10.5/pg10/../pg10/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control":
>   No such file or directory

The cause appears to be an incorrect path (an extra postgresql). It should be:
`"C:/POSTGR~1/10.5/pg10/../pg10/share/extension/postgis.control"`

This PostGIS installer that I used is: http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg10/postgis-bundle-pg10x64-setup-2.5.0-1.exe

And I am running ***PostgreSQL 10.5 on x86_64-pc-mingw64, compiled by gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 4.9.2, 64-bit***

While my question is a near duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71476/31, the issue is specific to PostgreSQL 10/PostGIS 2.5, and I don't think the answer is necessarily the same (since there is no spatial_ref_sys.sql file).

Is there way to correct the error? If not, which files in the extension directory have to run (and in which order) to create the PostGIS extension?

Comment: Unfortunately I still ran in the middle of 2019 in this mistake. First of all, it's not a special PG10/PostGIS-2.5 problem. I tested several combinations with Ubuntu under Docker. The problem are the missing links at the expected location. Sadly Postgres has the version number in the path. The solution is still the exact installation with the version numbers. Especially the package `postgresql-XX-postgis-Y.Z-scripts` provides the matching file associations. Here is the installation part of a working Dockerfile: ```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ software-propertie

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this question and answer on stackoverflow.com for PostgreSQL 9.6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806784/how-to-alter-the-path-for-postgres-looking-for-extensions.

This answer also works for PostgreSQL 10.

I first moved all files from `.\share\extension` to  `.\share\postgresql\extension` and re-ran the `create extension postgis`. As expected, I received this error: `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory`.  Which I figured, but I wanted to see what the exact error would be.

Then I moved the files in `.\lib` into `.\lib\postgresql` and now the `create extension postgis` works.

Answer (score 5):

The command below resolved my case:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-scripts
```

Answer (score 4):

Download binary of the desired version of postgis and add extensions files in lib and share/extension folder of postgresql. Hopefully, this issue will be resolved.

Comment: `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/postgis/files?type=conda`, in win location : `..anaconda3\envs\...\Library\share\extension`

Answer (score 1):

For windows, use stackbuilder > spatial extensions > PostGIS 3.1 Bundle for PostgreSQL